# Image srcset not working as desired for responsive page

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I  have a simple responsive and i want to use Img srcset feature to serve images based on device/screen size.

I tried it two ways first one works and serves the Mobile, Tablet or desktop version of image based on the device size or closest match

**Option 1**

```
<picture class="livery-imgset">
  <source srcset="Images/livery_mobile.jpg" media="(max-width: 500px)">
  <source srcset="Images/livery_tablet.jpg" media="(max-width: 768px)">
  <source srcset="Images/livery_desktop.jpg" media="(min-width: 769px)">
  <img src="Images/livery_desktop.jpg" alt="Offers">
</picture>
```

Option 1 code works fine and serves mobile version of image if screen width smaller than 501 pixels; serves tablet version if screens width is between 501px & 768px; and serves desktop version of screen is larger than 768px.

**Option 2**
I wanted to try same with Option 2, but it only serves desktop version of image. not sure what is wrong with the code

```
<img class="livery-imgset" src="Images/livery_desktop.jpg"
    srcset="Images/livery_mobile.jpg 414w,
            Images/livery_tablet.jpg 768w,
            Images/livery_desktop.jpg 1200w" 
    sizes="(min-width:1200px) 1050px, 100vw" alt="Offers" />
```

Also which is more practical option to be used for page performance when it comes to responsive images `<Picture Srcset=...` or `<Image Scrset=...`

Comment: I notice you have 2 slashes in one of the image locations. Could that be it?

Comment: @wazz, No it was a typo as i removed the actual path which was quite long..